# STMap in blender

Tags: rendering, tracking

I've had a 3rd party team track my camera shots and provide Alembic and STMap files, with the geometry loaded into a Blender file for me to model CGI additions.

I can't work out how to import the STMap file to correctly distort the render to match the footage in the compositor, or in the camera.

How do you do this? I have both a distort and undistort file from them.